# How do I fetch frontend input from with express WITHOUT using <form>

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, crud

I am randomly wondering how to get information based on input without using the <form method = "POST" ....> using express.js how would I access the req.body of something like this from the without using a form entry on the front end? - just curious

Comment: Make an async request using JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to send data in an HTTP request.

How are you sending your HTTP requests from the front-end - perhaps Axios?  That's a detail worth providing in your question.

For an Axios POST method, you can provide a request body as the second parameter, with the first parameter being the URL.  See the Axios documentation here: https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example

```js
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The second parameter is a simple JavaScript object.  To populate req.body, use body-parsing middleware such as express.json().
https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

If you're just using an API platform tool like Postman, then in your request Body you can choose "raw" from the radio button and then JSON from the dropdown.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this insight. I genuinely appreciate your input. Yes I was just curious if it was possible to do without form. Not sure why I would but just my brain wondering! Thanks I appreciate your helpfulness!